# IllegalStateException: Expected configuration ':module:debugFeatureCompileClasspath' to contain exactly one file, however, it contains 2 files

Tags: android, kotlin, android-instant-apps, android-wear-2.0

I am working with multi feature android application with instant app and wear app.Here i am able to ***successfully run my application*** but getting following error during ***building APK or rebuild projects***.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected configuration ':module1:debugFeatureCompileClasspath' to contain exactly one file, however, it contains 2 files.
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.getSingleFile(AbstractFileCollection.java:62)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeManifests.doFullTaskAction(MergeManifests.java:116)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
```

My project has 3-4 module and one base module projects. 
I have already integrated all setup for multi feature instant app as per sample provide by google. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/tree/master/multi-feature-module

I have one module(**apimodule**) where i have added all libraries and API dependencies. Following is my project dependencies structure.

1. AppModule

Added all module as implementation

```
implementation project(':base')
implementation project(':module1')
implementation project(':module2')
implementation project(':module3')
wearApp project(':wear')
```

2. BaseModule ( Also added `application project(':app')` )

Added `baseFeature true` in gradle

```
feature project(':module1')
feature project(':module2')
feature project(':module3')
api project(':apimodule')
```

3. apimodule

Added `baseFeature true` in gradle

Here is my one module1 gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation project(':base')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

}
```

Comment: Can you share relevant parts of build.gradle for module1?

Comment: Yes updated question with module1 gradle.

Comment: What `com.android.tools.build:gradle` are you using? Could you try a different version? https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin A search for "to contain exactly one file, however it contains 2 files.", unrelated to instant apps, shows some people resolved it with using a different version.

Comment: Also, can you remove the duplicate `feature project(':module1')` in your base module.

Comment: @TWL Already tried but no luck. module1 is my typing mistake.

Comment: Your question mentions that you added `baseFeature true` to both apiModule and BaseModule, is this true? I don't think you can have 2 base features in the same instant app. The `apimodule` should be a normal library module, then it will be shipped within your baseFeature APK.

Comment: Just checked the same and i can not remove just baseFeature true from one module. I have to refactor all code of APImodule into base module.

Comment: I guess you can just include it as a library in baseModule, then you would have one base APK, but your mileage may vary of course, depending on project structure.

Comment: Yes done it same already and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my question I have added `baseFeature true` in two gradle files. One of **base module** gradle and one **API module** gradle and API module added as dependency project in base module.

What I have done is that refactor all code of **API module** into base module and make only one **base module** with `baseFeature true`.

This is only case solved my problem.